# Group row summary in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a serious problem with [SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services) 2005:

Then, I have a group. This group includes, for example, 30 rows. All these rows have a special ID column that has a values from 1 to 10 (1-10, 1-10, 1-10). The group header also has 10 rows.

My problem is that I need to calculate a SUM for all rows included in this group, but I should do it in very strange way - my first cell in group header column should have a summary for all rows in the same column (and the same group) where ID field equals to 1. The second cell in this group header column should include a summary of all rows in the same group where ID field = 2, etc.

In some pseudo language it looks like the following:

The first cell in the group header:

```
"select sum(someDataField) from allRowsInGroup where ID = 1"
```

The second cell in the group header:

```
"select sum(someDataField) from allRowsInGroup where ID = 2"` and so on...
```

How do I make it in reporting services?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you are trying to construct the equivalent of a pivot table in your report. You *can* do this through expressions - something like:

```
=sum( iif(Fields!id.Value=1, Fields!someDataField.Value, 0) )
```

- but SSRS already includes its own version of pivot tables, in the form of the Matrix report item.

You can find out more about SSRS Matrixes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One of  my suggestion is that if your column and rows are not dynamic, you can use of expression in SQL Server Reporting Services. For some help, refer to *[Using Report Functions in Expressions (Reporting Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159673%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)* (MSDN).

Comment: Yes, i know about expressions, but they can not help me. Is there a variation of Sum() function that can help me to summarize certain cells inside group where some other column equals to 1? Pseudo code: =(Sum(AllCellsInMyGroup) where ID (other column in the same table) = 1)